# Porque no me filtra los inputs cuando ingreso algo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Estoy creando unos filtros para mi tabla con jQuery pero cuando escribo algo no lo filtra y nose porque.

```
@section('javascripts')

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#datatable').Datatable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'ajax': "{{ route('products.view') }}",
            'columns': [
                {'data': 'id'},
                {'data': 'brandName'},
                {'data': 'modelName'}
            ],
        });

        $('.filter-input').keyup(function() {
            table.column( $(this).data('column'))
                .search( $(this).val())
                .draw();
        });
    })
</script>

@endsection
```

Estos son mis inputs que deberían funcionar como filtro de busqueda:

```
<tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por id..." data-column="0">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por marca..." data-column="1">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control filter-input" placeholder="Buscar por modelo..." data-column="2">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
```

Esta es mi tabla y los datos que contiene:

```
                                        <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{$product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product['ptype']['productType']}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->marca->brandName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->coin }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->description }}</td>
                                    
                                    <td>{{ $product->cost }}</td>
```

Cuando escribo algo en el input no sucede nada, es como si no identificase las columnas pero en la consola no aparece ningun error.